# C# regex fails to split string by pipe delimiter

Tags: c#, regex, split

```
string query = "A|B";
```

The output of the next 2 lines are equal to `"%A%|%B%"` whereas "A%B" is expected!

```
query = Regex.Replace(query, "|", "%");
query = Regex.Replace(query, @"|", "%");
```

Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The `|` is a special character of regexes, it means "or"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference#alternation-constructs). You have to escape it.

```
query = Regex.Replace(query, @"\|", "%");
```